# Trigger in Trigger

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is it possible to do this? I want to set IsMouseOver when there's a validation error occur.

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxInError"
       TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
                 Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
                          Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="3" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Red" />
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                        Value="Red" />
            </Trigger>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

A MultiTrigger can contain multiple conditions.